# Contruct Tree from table

Tags: java, oracle, recursion, tree

I have a table in my database like this:

[image]

and so on...

As you can see there are several root parents (the ones which have no parent_id) and every category has n childs.

i want to convert this to a tree structure in Java using this class:

```
private int id;
private String name;
private int parent;
private List<Category> children;
```

I get data with this query, i think it could be improve:

```
SELECT c.*, ca.name, NVL(ca.parent_id, -1) AS parent_id FROM 
( 
    SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM categories 
) ca, 
( 
    SELECT LISTAGG(id || ':' || name || ':' || DECODE(parent_id, NULL, 
    DECODE(id,    NULL, NULL, -1), parent_id), ';') 
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS  children, parent_id AS id 
    FROM categories 
    GROUP BY parent_id HAVING parent_id IS NOT NULL 
) c 
WHERE c.id = ca.id
```

I get every category (id, name and parent_id) and a string with its children.

Then i loop throw every ResultSet

```
List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

while (rs.next()) { 
    Category c = new Category();
    c = JdbcToModel.convertToCategory(rs); //
    if (c.getParent() == -1) { // parent_id is null in database
        categories.add(c);
     else {
        categories = JdbcToModel.addCategoryToTree(categories, c);

    }
}
```

The method *convertToCategory*:

public static Category convertToCategory(ResultSet rs) {

```
Category toRet = new Category();
List<Category> children = new ArrayList<Category>();
try {       
    children = parseCategoriesFromReview(rs.getString("children"));
    toRet.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    toRet.setName(rs.getString("name"));
    toRet.setParent(rs.getInt("parent_id"));
    toRet.setChildren(children);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return toRet;
```

}

The method *parseCategoriesFromReview* when i parse the string of childs:

```
public static List<Category> parseCategoriesFromReview(String categoriesString) {

        List<Category> toRet = new ArrayList<Category>();
        try {       
            if (!categoriesString.equals("::")) {

                String [] categs = categoriesString.split(";");
                for (String categ : categs) {
                    String [] category = categ.split(":");
                    Category c = new Category(Integer.parseInt(category[0]), category[1], Integer.parseInt(category[2]), new ArrayList<Category>());
                    toRet.add(c);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return toRet;   
    }
```

And the recursive method *addCategoryToTree*:

```
public static List<Category> addCategoryToTree(List<Category> categories, Category c) { 
    try {       
        for (Category ct : categories) {
            if (ct.getId() == c.getParent()) {
                ct.getChildren().add(c);
                break;
            } else {
                return addCategoryToTree(ct.getChildren(), c);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return categories;

}
```

I think that the big problem is in this method... I never wrote a recursive method with a loop inside and i don't know if it's correct. The point is i get a tree structure but with just a few categories. The final tree does not have so many of them.

Maybe i am making things complicated but i don't know how to do it in another way..

Anyone help??

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE categories ( id, name, parent_id ) AS
SELECT  1, 'Restauracion', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'Desayuno',        1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'Calidad',         2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 'Organizacion',    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 'Variedad',        2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 'Personal',     NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 'Pisos',           6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 'Falta de Personal', 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 'Trato',           7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'Informacion',     7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'Idiomas',         7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'Otros',           7 FROM DUAL;
```

**Java**:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Category {
    private final String name;
    private final int id;
    private final Category parent;
    private final ArrayList<Category> children = new ArrayList<>();

    private Category(final String name, final int id, final Category parent) {
        this.name   = name;
        this.id     = id;
        this.parent = parent;
        if ( parent != null )
            parent.children.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append( '<' );
        buffer.append(name);
        buffer.append(':');
        buffer.append(id);
        buffer.append(':');
        buffer.append(parent == null ? "" : parent.name );
        buffer.append( '>' );
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public String toHierarchyString(){
        return toHierarchyString(0);
    }

    private String toHierarchyString( int level ){
        final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for ( int i = 0; i < level; i++ )
            buffer.append('\t');
        buffer.append( toString() );
        buffer.append( '\n' );
        for ( final Category child : children )
            buffer.append( child.toHierarchyString(level+1));
        return buffer.toString();
    }
    public static ArrayList<Category> loadCategoriesFromDatabase(){
        try{

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

            final Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","TEST","TEST");
            final PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(
                    "SELECT id, name, parent_id " +
                    "FROM  categories " +
                    "START WITH parent_id IS NULL " +
                    "CONNECT BY PRIOR id = PARENT_ID " +
                    "ORDER SIBLINGS BY name"
            );

            final ResultSet cursor = st.executeQuery();

            final HashMap<Integer,Category> categoryMap = new HashMap<>();
            final ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();

            while ( cursor.next() )
            {
                final String name       = cursor.getString("NAME");
                final int id            = cursor.getInt("ID");
                final Integer parent_id = cursor.getInt("PARENT_ID");
                final Category parent   = categoryMap.get( parent_id );
                final Category category = new Category( name, id, parent );
                categoryMap.put(id, category);
                if ( parent == null )
                    categories.add(category);
            }
            return categories;
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main( final String[] args ){
        ArrayList<Category> categories = loadCategoriesFromDatabase();
        for ( final Category cat : categories )
            System.out.println( cat.toHierarchyString() );
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
<Personal:6:>
    <Pisos:7:Personal>
        <Falta de Personal:8:Pisos>
        <Idiomas:11:Pisos>
        <Informacion:10:Pisos>
        <Otros:12:Pisos>
        <Trato:9:Pisos>

<Restauracion:1:>
    <Desayuno:2:Restauracion>
        <Calidad:3:Desayuno>
        <Organizacion:4:Desayuno>
        <Variedad:5:Desayuno>
```

Comment: it works like a charm!! That is what i wanted. Thank you so much MT0!"

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem lies in the sorting of the results. Your code assumes, that all child ids have a higher ID than all parent IDs, which does not need to be the case at all. E.g. if you have a category(id=5, parent=10), then it will recurse the current tree (containing category id's 0 to 4). It will not find the correct parent category and in that case (depending if the `children` field in your category class is initialized to `null` or an empty list) will either print the stack trace of an exception, or just iterate over an empty for loop in all the leaf categories and do nothing.

To build a tree from such a data structure, you will probably need a two phase approach. The one I prefer (because it's quite the simplest, although not really performant) would be:

- Initialize a `HashMap<Integer, List<Category>>`
- loop through your DB result items and do `mapFromAbove.get(category.getId()).add(category)` (you will also need to initialize these lists)
- once done, do `mapFromAbove.get(0)`, and iterate over the results, for each result, get the children from the same hash map and add it to them. then do this recursively.

It's actually quite easy to implement.

Comment: Ok. I understand the first two  points but i get lost at last one.

Comment: Map<Integer, List<Category>> categories = new HashMap<Integer, List<Category>>();  categories.put(category.getId(), new ArrayList<Category>()); categories.get(category.getId()).add(category)) but i get lost at last one. When you say mapFromAbove.get(0) what do you mean???Should it be a variable i?

Comment: mapFromAbove.get(0) will return you all categories with parent Id 0 (which are all categories that are the root)